# Can I do $pagenow on query pages like admin.php?page=example?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working with...

```
global $pagenow;
    if(in_array($pagenow, array('example1.php','example2.php'))) {}
```

In Wordpress this works fine for enqueuing admin scripts on only their needed admin pages.

Is there a way to apply this same concept to query pages?

Example:

```
global $pagenow;
        if(in_array($pagenow, array('example1.php?page=example1','example2.php?page=example1'))) {}
```

There are some plugins I am trying to make load more efficiently in my set up but some use the page query for their pages and the above code doesn't work.

I'm not finding anything online for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
if ( isset($_GET['page']) ) {
    global $pagenow;
    if( in_array( $pagenow, array('example1.php','example2.php') ) && ( $_GET['page'] == 'example1' || $_GET['page'] == 'example1' ) ) {}
}
```

Comment: This works great! One question though... How can I exclude the admin.php from loading it's resources? Others plugins use the "admin.php" so with code above plugins that both use the admin.php load. I would like with the code above to have that plugin only load based on its query. Make sense?